Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'Flutter'
I recently encountered an issue with my Flutter application on iOS. When I try to run the application, I get the following error message:
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'Flutter'
/Users/victorpelle/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/url_launcher_ios-6.3.1/ios/url_launcher_ios/Sources/url_launcher_ios/messages.g.swift:9:9


Swift Compiler Error (Xcode): No such module 'Flutter'
/Users/victorpelle/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/path_provider_foundation-2.4.0/darwin/path_provider_foundation/Sources/path_provider_foundation/messages.g.swift:9:9


Uncategorized (Xcode): Command SwiftEmitModule failed with a nonzero exit code



Error launching application on eziopelle’s iPhone.

I've already tried several things:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
pod install
pod update

I’ve also closed Xcode, tried deleting my Podfile.lock, but nothing seems to work.
Here’s my launcher:
// Copyright 2013 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

import UIKit

/// Protocol for UIApplication methods relating to launching URLs.
///
/// This protocol exists to allow injecting an alternate implementation for testing.
protocol Launcher {
  /// Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether an app is available to handle a URL scheme.
  func canOpenURL(_ url: URL) -> Bool

  /// Attempts to asynchronously open the resource at the specified URL.
  func open(
    _ url: URL,
    options: [UIApplication.OpenExternalURLOptionsKey: Any],
    completionHandler completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?)
}

/// Launcher is intentionally a direct passthroguh to UIApplication.
extension UIApplication: Launcher {}

Can you please help me resolve this error?

What is the output of flutter doctor?

  flutter doctor -v                                                                                                                                                                                    [ system]
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.24.3, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 3.24.3 on channel stable at /Users/victorpelle/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 2663184aa7 (4 weeks ago), 2024-09-11 16:27:48 -0500
    • Engine revision 36335019a8
    • Dart version 3.5.3
    • DevTools version 2.37.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/victorpelle/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/victorpelle/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 16A242d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.3)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.94.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.98.0

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • eziopelle’s iPhone (mobile) • 00008110-001078243A61801E • ios            • iOS 18.0.1 22A3370
    • macOS (desktop)             • macos      

           • darwin-x64     • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-x64
• Chrome (web)                • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 129.0.6668.90

[✓] Network resources
• All expected network resources are available.
• No issues found!

This is not an answer. you can edit your question and add flutter doctor output in it.
